# Using Firebug and jsfiddle.net to test a function

Tags: javascript, firebug, jsfiddle

Im a newbie programmer who got the function below from Stoyan Stefanovs object oriented JavaScript Book. He says that if you call next three times, it will output "a" and "b" and then "c".  When I tried it in firebug console, it kept giving me "a", so that`s one question (a) i.e. is there something about firebug that would explain my result?

Next, I tried to run it in jsfiddle.net but it won`t output anything. http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/SkSMm/

I`m sure I`m doing something wrong, but what? Please explain if you can.  Note, I did next(); and got A, and then I did next(); again and got 'a' and next(); again and got 'a'. In other words, the counter didn`t change or didn`t remember.

```
function setup(x) {
   var i = 0;
   return function () {
        return x[i++];
    };
}

var next = setup(['a','b','c']);

next();
```

Comment: but you only called next() one time. try calling it thrice like next(); next(); next(); and that should show your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it wrong:
[image]

And jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZHgW2/

Comment: I don`t see a difference between your code and mine. I did next(); and got 'a' and then did next(); again and got 'a'.

Comment: and also, what about the fiddle I did. Can you explain that? thank you.

Comment: you fiddle calls `next()`, but does nothing with the result. The function works correctly, but you don't output the result anywhere.

Comment: Also, to explain why it works with firebug: firebug also outputs the function results. Try typing just `2` in the console. It will output it back. This is what happens in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jsfiddle link to show it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZnZTk/

Answer (score 1):

JsFiddle is not like the console, it doesn't have a window where it will output return values. The result of the code is a web page, that is shown at the lower right.

You can use the `alert` method to show the values:

```
alert(next());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SkSMm/4/

As you see, calling `next` three times will actually output the three values in the array. The `setup` function returns a delegate to the anonumous function that is created in the function. As that anonymous function uses variables outside itself, but which are local to the surrounding function, a closure is created for the function. The closure will contain the `i` and `x` variables. As the closure belongs to the delegate, it will survive from one function call to the next, and retain the values of it's variables.

You could do a similar thing just using global variables:

```
var x = ['a','b','c'];
var i = 0;

function next() {
  return x[i++];
}

alert(next());
alert(next());
alert(next());
```

As the variables are declared outside the function, they will survive between the function calls.

The drawback of using global variables is that one script easily clashes with another if the variables are not given very unique names. If you use a closure, there is no risk of the variables of one script to conflict with variables of another script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat demo that takes advantage of an [imported `say` function](http://entvibes.com/web/js/jqia2.support.js) and relies on a button:

http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/wxTqR/

This is a great way to test your scripts without relying on the log or alerts.

The `say` function is from jQuery in Action. Excerpt:

> *Within this function, we employ the services of a small utility function, say() C,
> that we use to emit text messages to a dynamically created  element on the page
> that we’ll call the “console.” This function is declared within the imported support
> script file (jqia2.support.js), and will save us the trouble of using annoying and disruptive alerts to indicate when things happen on our page. We’ll be using this handy function in many of the examples throughout the remainder of the book.*